# Native binary libraries containing duplicate composite symbols error

Tags: aix, gcc, cmake

I am compiling a C/C++ library from source using GCC. The bulk of code was written for Unix with an emphasis for Linux kernels. I've been trying to adapt it for AIX. The majority of the changes I have made have just been to add flags labels and conditions specific to AIX which, hypothetically speaking, should not break the code. However, I am encountering the following duplicate symbol warning for `.__init_aix_libgcc_cxa_atexit` which on inspection is a composite symbol, created either at precompile or compile time.

The warning

```
ld: 0711-228 WARNING: Duplicate symbols were found while resolving symbols.
    The following duplicates were found:
 Symbol                    Source-File(Object) OR Import-File{Shared-object}
 ------------------------- -------------------------------------------------
 .__init_aix_libgcc_cxa_atexit ../../../../../gcc-9.1.0/libgcc/config/rs6000/crtcxa.c(/opt/freeware/lib/gcc/powerpc-ibm-aix7.1.0.0/9.1.0/pthread/ppc64/crtcxa.o)
    ** Duplicate **        {../../../target/usr/local/lib/libhdfs.so}
RESOLVE: 176 of 5701 symbols were kept.
RESOLVE: The return code is 4.
```

Additional info:
AIX 7.1
CMAKE 3.15.0
GCC 9.1-AIX-7.1

I have search the source codes and build scripts and I can't seem to find an issue. I have forced the compiler to use C99 and C++ 11 standards, so that shouldn't be a problem. It would be great if someone could give me a bit more guidance on where I should look or how I could work around this issue as I am suspecting that this 'warning' is causing downstream compile errors.

Please let me know if anything else is required.

Comment: On AIX, when building a shared library, you should create an _export file,_ not just use linker option _-bexpall._ Details here: http://lzsiga.users.sourceforge.net/aix-linking.html

Comment: Note: `libtool` could do that automagically.